# Activity disappears on screen off by proximity sensor

Tags: android

I've an activity dialog that is displayed when the activity receives a custom broadcast intent filter.  The application uses the proximity sensor to turn the screen off.  But when the screen turns on again, the dialog disappears. How can I prevent the dialog from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

use flags in Activity

When screen off it just recreate activity 
then onCreate method is call so Activity re initialize it self and all content is reloaded

If you set configChanges flag in your activity it does not recreate the activity just resume it

Do this is your manifest file where you define your activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
            android:label="MYLabel" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: it's better than before for sure

Answer (score 0):

yourDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

This will not let screen go off while your dialog is visible.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But I require the screen to turn off and display the dialog again when it wakes.

Comment: It's a bad policy to mess with the user interaction workflow in an unexpected manner. I advise against this kind of solution.

Comment: Your activity is (possibly) being closed when the screen goes off. and restarted when it returns in the normal android activity lifecycle.

To retain your dialog, you would need to save its state when the activity closes and reshow it when it returns.

You can demonstrate this by recreating the dialog again

Comment: @STTLCU yes let user do what ever he/she wants handle it pragmatically